# Reproject by GDAL GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT in C

Tags: c, gdal, reprojection-error

I want to re-project an HDF from UTM(WGS84) to sinusoidal（WGS84), so I try to use `GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT` to finished it. The code is below:

```
hSrcDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen("HJ1ACCD1.hdf", GA_ReadOnly);
const char *pszSrcWKT = NULL;
char*  pszDstWKT = NULL;
//pszSrcWKT = ProjectionStr;
pszSrcWKT=GDALGetProjectionRef(hSrcDS);
CPLAssert( pszSrcWKT != NULL &&strlen(pszSrcWKT) > 0 );

OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
oSRS.SetSinusoidal(0,0,0);
oSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
oSRS.exportToWkt(&pszDstWKT );

GDALWarpOptions*psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();  
psWarpOptions->dfWarpMemoryLimit=500*1024*1024;

hDstDS=(GDALDataset*)(GDALDataset*)GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT(hSrcDS,pszSrcWKT,pszDstWKT,GRA_Bilinear ,20,psWarpOptions);
GDALDriver *poDriverTiff;
poDriverTiff=GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTIFF");
poDriverTiff->CreateCopy("d:\\toto.tif",(GDALDataset*)hDstDS,false,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

When I set `oSRS.SetSinusoidal(0,0,0)`，the result seems good, but the resolution is doubled (from 30 to 60). It's so weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the API docs for `GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180418112306/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdalwarper_8h.html#ab5a8723d68786e7554f1ad4c0a6fa8d3):

> The [GDALSuggestedWarpOutput()](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716151832/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__alg_8h.html#a816819e7495bfce06dbd110f7c57af65) function is used to determine the bounds and resolution of the output virtual file which should be large enough to include all the input image

There is also a [GDALSuggestedWarpOutput2() function](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716151832/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__alg_8h.html#a8ae26881b86e42ff958a8e81c4976fb3) to help suggest output file size for a similar set of requirements.